# Android Modbus RTU library

Tags: android, modbus

Do apologize for the question I know its been in discussion before but I could not find the answer. I am trying to create an app to communicate over Modbus RTU with our Micro-controller. Is there any library available for Modbus RTU for Android or I have to write the whole code by my self.?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.biemmeitalia.net/libraries/ please look into this

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade I am actually looking into it but to be honest did not find it really helpful

Comment: please look into my ans\

Comment: any library for 2022 ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this library works with Android. What you need to do is simply read the documentation first and proove the communication with only serial port after that you can easily implement the library.

[Modbus RTU Java Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jamod/files/jamod/1.2/)

Check this [Link](https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio) for how to implement the library in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

There are library present which will help you.

> 1) [simplemodbusng](https://github.com/angeloc/simplemodbusng)

SimpleModbus is a collection of Arduino libraries that enables you to communicate serially using the Modicon Modbus RTU protocol.

> 2) [Modbus-RTU-Serial-for-Android](https://github.com/JBInvestments/Modbus-RTU-Serial-for-Android)

This repository includes Android code that is needed to communicate modbus RTU serial through the microUSB port.

Comment: The first one is simple not applicable because its for simply Modbus tool and the second one is something I need to look but How can I use this . that's one hell of a question.

Comment: @Muhammed its library you have to read the document and use it.